# Is the procedure correct to write Characteristic in Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a button in MainActivity which is used to write a `byte[]` to BLE device:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Write Char"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="onClickWrite" />
```

And the function `onClickWrite` is

```
public void onClickWrite(View v){
    if(mBluetoothLeService != null) {
       byte [] data= new byte[3];
       data[0] = (byte)(0 & 0xFF);
       data[1] = (byte)(255 & 0xFF);
       data[2] = (byte)(0 & 0xFF);
       mBluetoothLeService.sendData(data);
    }
}
```

where `sendData` is a modified function in class `[BluetoothLeService][1]`. It worked well when I press the button. However, Let is careful to look at the  `sendData` function. It searches service and Characteristic again when I press the button. Is it correct procedure for write a Characteristic in BLE?

```
public void sendData(byte[] data){
    String lService = "00001c00-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5A5";
    String lCharacteristic = "00001c03-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5";
    BluetoothGattService mBluetoothLeService = null;
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mBluetoothGattCharacteristic = null;

    for (BluetoothGattService service : mBluetoothGatt.getServices()) {
        if ((service == null) || (service.getUuid() == null)) {

            Log.d("TAG","Something is null");
            continue;
        }
        if (lService.equalsIgnoreCase(service.getUuid().toString())) {

            Log.d("TAG","service.getUuid().toString()="+service.getUuid().toString());
            mBluetoothLeService = service;
        }
    }
    if(mBluetoothLeService!=null) {
        mBluetoothGattCharacteristic =
                mBluetoothLeService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(lRgbCharacteristic));
    }
    else{
        Log.d("TAG","mBluetoothLeService is null");
    }

    if(mBluetoothGattCharacteristic!=null) {
        mBluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(data);

        boolean write = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mBluetoothGattCharacteristic);

        Log.d("TAG","writeCharacteristic:"+write);
    }
    else{
        Log.d("TAG", "mBluetoothGattCharacteristic is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: not bad; but you may also consider a handler to parse the data

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

(filling unnecessarily required length)

Comment: However, the code repeat looks up and open service when I click the button. Do we have the way to open just one time

Comment: Do the lookup just once after services are discovered, assign the proper service to the local variable and remove the lookup code in your button handler.

Comment: So my code is right as you said. It is normal way for write a to BLE.